# Postgresql-Select one row from table where value in many table matches?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, call them a and b, where a is related to b in a one-to-many relationship. I would like to select any rows from table a where any of the many related records in table b match a criteria. A basic join doesn't work, because that will return one result for each row in table b that matches - I just want one result for each row in table a with one or more related records matching.

For simplified example, say I have a table Departments and related table Employees, where each employee has one department, but each department obviously can have multiple employees. I want a query that will give me one row per department that has one or more employees matching a given criteria - say the departments that have one or more employees that have earned "employee of the month". How would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM department d
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM employee e
   JOIN badges b ON b.person_id = e.person_id AND b.badge = 'EotM'
   WHERE e.dep_id = d.dep_id
   AND e.gender = 'F'
   );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct on (d.id)
    d.name
from
    department d
    inner join
    employee e on d.id = e.department_id
where e.age between 60 and 65
```

How to order it by any column:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (d.id)
        d.*
    from
        department d
        inner join
        employee e on d.id = e.department_id
    where e.age between 60 and 65
) s
order by name
```

Comment: I like this approach because it fits nicely into my workflow, and doesn't use any subqueries. However, it would appear that have to use the expression in the distinct clause as the initial order by, which kinda stinks.

Comment: @ibrewster I updated with a version where it is possible to order by any column. With that said and done the accepted answer using `exists` will be faster.

Comment: Yep, that works. As you said, though, exists is faster, and for the specific application I am working on, that is essential. Shame though, cause I actually like your answer better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like  a job for a subquery.  Something like:  Select * from dept where id in (select deptID from Emp where wasEOTM = true); ought to do the job.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Now I feel stupid for not thinking of it. I guess I was just fixated on joins :P

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto Thanks for the heads up, but some quick testing using explain analyze on my database shows this method to be roughly twice as fast as what you proposed (SELECT DISTINCT ON). Of course, I like your proposal because it leaves the WHERE clause as just criteria, which makes it fit into my existing workflow easier.